# PHP echo/print a function call that's inside a variable

Tags: php, function, variables

How would I go about putting function calls into a variable and then echo or printing them repeatedly?

Currently I have this code which is calling the PHP function "chords" 24 times. The functions are in groups of six so I would like to condense that six. I would like to scale this up though only once I have the code looking nicer and running more efficiently.

```
            <?php 
                $chord_name = 'A 7';
                $i1 = '4';
                $i2 = '7';
                $i3 = '10';
            ?>
                <div id="chords_wrapper" class="chords_wrapper">
                    <? echo $fretnumbers; ?>
                    <h1><? echo $chord_name; ?></h1>
                    <ul><?php chords (6); ?></ul>
                    <ul><?php chords (5); ?></ul>
                    <ul><?php chords (4); ?></ul>
                    <ul><?php chords (3); ?></ul>
                    <ul><?php chords (2); ?></ul>
                    <ul><?php chords (1); ?></ul>
                </div>


            <?php 
                $chord_name = 'A Minor';
                $i1 = '3';
                $i2 = '7';
                $i3 = '0';
            ?>
                <div id="chords_wrapper" class="chords_wrapper">
                    <? echo $fretnumbers; ?>
                    <h1><? echo $chord_name; ?></h1>
                    <ul><?php chords (6); ?></ul>
                    <ul><?php chords (5); ?></ul>
                    <ul><?php chords (4); ?></ul>
                    <ul><?php chords (3); ?></ul>
                    <ul><?php chords (2); ?></ul>
                    <ul><?php chords (1); ?></ul>
                </div>


            <?php 
                $chord_name = 'A Minor 7';
                $i1 = '3';
                $i2 = '7';
                $i3 = '10';
            ?>
                <div id="chords_wrapper" class="chords_wrapper">
                    <? echo $fretnumbers; ?>
                    <h1><? echo $chord_name; ?></h1>
                    <ul><?php chords (6); ?></ul>
                    <ul><?php chords (5); ?></ul>
                    <ul><?php chords (4); ?></ul>
                    <ul><?php chords (3); ?></ul>
                    <ul><?php chords (2); ?></ul>
                    <ul><?php chords (1); ?></ul>
                </div>


        <div style="width:620px; text-align:center; clear:both;">

        </div>


    </div>
```

I would like to have it look something like this so that each group of functions can be seen more easy and tidy up the code. I have tried this but it displays the php code without executing it.

```
<?php
    $kn = '25';
    $chord_dump = '<div id="chords_wrapper" class="chords_wrapper">
            <? echo $fretnumbers; ?>
            <h1>'.$chord_name.'</h1>
            <ul><?php chords (6); ?></ul>
            <ul><?php chords (5); ?></ul>
            <ul><?php chords (4); ?></ul>
            <ul><?php chords (3); ?></ul>
            <ul><?php chords (2); ?></ul>
            <ul><?php chords (1); ?></ul>
        </div>';
    ?>
    <div id="chords_set">
            <?php 
        // A Major
                $i1 = '4';
                $i2 = '7';
                $i3 = '0';
                $chord_name = 'A Major';
                echo $chord_dump;


        // A 7

                $i1 = '4';
                $i2 = '7';
                $i3 = '10';
                $chord_name = 'A 7';
                echo $chord_dump;


        // A Minor

                $i1 = '3';
                $i2 = '7';
                $i3 = '0';
                $chord_name = 'A Minor';
                echo $chord_dump;


        // A Minor 7

                $i1 = '3';
                $i2 = '7';
                $i3 = '10';
                $chord_name = 'A Minor 7';
                echo $chord_dump;
            ?>


        <div style="width:620px; text-align:center; clear:both;">

        </div>


    </div>
```

The chord function

```
    <? 



    function chords ($funtion_string) {
        /*$chrd_tn ="CGCFCE";
        $tuning_capo =0;*/
        $chrd_tn = $GLOBALS['chrd_tn'];
        $tuning_capo = $GLOBALS['tuning_capo'];
        $notes_array = '';
        // Select Chord Key Notes
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `guitar_tunings_chords` WHERE note_id - ".$GLOBALS['kn']." >= 0 AND ( (( note_id - ".$GLOBALS['kn'].") % 12 ) = ".$GLOBALS['i1']." OR ( (note_id-".$GLOBALS['kn'].") % 12 ) = ".$GLOBALS['i2']." OR ( (note_id-".$GLOBALS['kn'].") % 12 ) = ".$GLOBALS['i3']." OR ( note_id - ".$GLOBALS['kn'].") % 12 = 0) LIMIT 24") or die(mysql_error());
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
        $notes2 = $row["note"]; 
        $notes2 = str_replace("#", "z", $notes2);
        $notes_array = ''.$notes2.','.$notes_array.'';
        }

            // Delete comma from end of chord notes array
            $notes_array = substr($notes_array,0,-1);

        // Counter to distinguish the nut from the fretboard
        $counter = 0;
        $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * 
    FROM `guitar_tunings_links`
    JOIN guitar_tunings_chords ON guitar_tunings_links.".$funtion_string." = guitar_tunings_chords.note
    WHERE tuning =  '".$chrd_tn."'") or die(mysql_error()); 
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result2) ) {
            $bridge_note = ($row["note_id"]);           
        }/*
        ?><BR>$chrd_tn  = <? var_dump ($chrd_tn); 
        ?><BR>$tuning_capo  = <? var_dump ($tuning_capo);
        ?><BR>$funtion_string  = <? var_dump ($funtion_string);  
        ?><BR>$key_note  = <? var_dump ($key_note); 
        ?><BR>$bridge_note  = <? var_dump ($bridge_note); 
        ?><BR><?*/

            // SELECT * FROM `guitar_tunings_chords` WHERE `note_id` >= 28 LIMIT 0,8
        $result4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `guitar_tunings_chords` WHERE `note_id` >= $bridge_note LIMIT $tuning_capo,8") or die(mysql_error());
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result4) ) {

            //Notes
            $note = ($row["note"]); 

            // Replace # with z
            $note = str_replace("#", "z", $note);

            // Distinguish nut notes on or off
            if (preg_match("/\b".$note."\b/i", $notes_array)) {
                $n_nut_style = 'note_nut_on';
            } else { $n_nut_style = 'note_nut_off'; 
            }

            // Distinguish fretboard notes on or off
            if (preg_match("/\b".$note."\b/i", $notes_array)) {
                $n_style = 'note_on';
            } else { $n_style = 'note_off'; 
            }

            // Print nut notes
            if ($counter < 1) {
                $str_prtou = '<li class="'.$n_nut_style.'">'.$note.'</li>';
                $numbers = array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8");
                $str_prtou = str_replace($numbers, "", $str_prtou);
            }

            // Print fretboard notes
            if ($counter > 0)       
            $str_prtou = ''.$str_prtou.'<li class="'.$n_style.'">'.$note.'</li>
            ';
            $counter++;
        }
        $str_prtou = str_replace("z", "#", $str_prtou);
        $numbers = array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8");
        $str_prtou = str_replace($numbers, "", $str_prtou);
        echo $str_prtou;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I'm sure that you can narrow this down to a testcase that takes a few lines.

Comment: The definition of the `chords` function is missing in your question and it looks like you're using global variables as function call parameters.

Comment: My Globals are defined like this in the function `$GLOBALS['i1']`  The function is working fine in the top code. but the in bottom code the php variable `$chord_dump` is not parsing the PHP

Comment: @warmwhisky: That's because of the global variables. As written, you should add the source of the `chords` function to your question because it contains some of your output logic so it's hard to mix with the output logic of the code you've posted. That's merely because of the globals you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be the solution, but it's bad style:

```
<?php
    $kn = '25';
    class chord_dump {
        public function __toString() {
            global $fretnumbers, $chord_name;
            return '<div id="chords_wrapper" class="chords_wrapper">
            '.$fretnumbers.'
            <h1>'.$chord_name.'</h1>
            <ul>'.chords(6).'</ul>
            <ul>'.chords(5).'</ul>
            <ul>'.chords(4).'</ul>
            <ul>'.chords(3).'</ul>
            <ul>'.chords(2).'</ul>
            <ul>'.chords(1).'</ul>
        </div>';
        }
    }
    $chord_dump = new chord_dump;
    ?>
```

You can then `echo` the `$chord_dump` variable and it will always execute the [`__toString`](http://php.net/__toString) function of the `cord_dump` class then:

```
<div id="chords_set">
        <?php 
    // A Major
            $i1 = '4';
            $i2 = '7';
            $i3 = '0';
            $chord_name = 'A Major';
            echo $chord_dump;


    // A 7

            $i1 = '4';
            $i2 = '7';
            $i3 = '10';
            $chord_name = 'A 7';
            echo $chord_dump;


    // A Minor

            $i1 = '3';
            $i2 = '7';
            $i3 = '0';
            $chord_name = 'A Minor';
            echo $chord_dump;


    // A Minor 7

            $i1 = '3';
            $i2 = '7';
            $i3 = '10';
            $chord_name = 'A Minor 7';
            echo $chord_dump;
        ?>


    <div style="width:620px; text-align:center; clear:both;">

    </div>


</div>
```

That's done by PHP when it converts the object to string (because the variable is used with `echo`, triggering the so called string-context).

But instead I suggest you remove the global variables and turn them into parameters. Additionally you could normalize each output-unit into a data-structure like an `Array` or `stdClass`, wrap them into an array, iterate over that array and create the output. That done you could easily extend both, what your program is doing as well as the output.

```
/* model */
$kn = '25';
$chords = array(        
    array(4, 7, 0, 'A Major'),
    array(4, 7, 10, 'A 7'),
    ...
);

/* output */
foreach ($chords as $chord_index => $chord)
{
    list($i1, $i2, $i3, $chord_name) = $chord;

    echo '<div id="chord_', $chord_index, '" class="chords_wrapper">'
          , $fretnumbers, '<h1>', $chord_name, '</h1>';
    foreach (range(6,1) as $i)
    {
        echo '<ul>', chords($i), '</ul>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Tim had answered this for me. But your second block of code is beautiful! This makes for great scalability! Thanks you very much Hakre. Though most of what you said goes over my head. Atleast I know what this code is doing and I can pick it apart to understand it better. On the parameter comment I don't actually know what they are. I'm self taught as I am a full time glass blower so I pick and scrap at what I can to understand programming.

Comment: @warmwhisky: I would be better able to just show you that if you had posted the `chord` function as well. That would make it much more practical and visible instead of just writing more or less abstract texts. I'd say the code below is much better and it's a common way to solve things as well, so it's not only useful in that specific case but more generally.

Comment: It's better than I imagined I wanted it to work. The possibilites to create chords for guitar are now so easy! It has made my projects a lot more managable in my head and look so clean in the code editor. I have posted the chord function if you are still interested in seeing it. I'm sure it wont be the most agreeable code you have seen!

Answer (score 1):

Just put your function inside a function.

```
function allChords(){
  ?>
  <div id="chords_wrapper" class="chords_wrapper">
    <? echo $fretnumbers; ?>
    <h1><? echo $chord_name; ?></h1>
    <ul><?php chords (6); ?></ul>
    <ul><?php chords (5); ?></ul>
    <ul><?php chords (4); ?></ul>
    <ul><?php chords (3); ?></ul>
    <ul><?php chords (2); ?></ul>
    <ul><?php chords (1); ?></ul>
  </div>
  <?php
}
```

Then, each time you want them all called, you just call `allChords()`.

Also, for your `chordDump` string, instead of putting `<?php ?>` tags inside of other `<?php ?>` tags, you simply use the `.` operator to append:

```
$chord_dump = '<div id="chords_wrapper" class="chords_wrapper">
        <? echo $fretnumbers; ?>
        <h1>' . $chord_name . '</h1>
        <ul>' . chords (6) . '</ul>
        <ul>' . chords (5) . '</ul>
        <ul>' . chords (4) . '</ul>
        <ul>' . chords (3) . '</ul>
        <ul>' . chords (2) . '</ul>
        <ul>' . chords (1) . '</ul>
    </div>';
```

However, for this to work, your `chords` function needs to *return* the value instead of *printing* it, as it seems to be doing now.  If your function **has** to print it, and there's no other option, you can use output buffering to capture the result, though it's probably way more advanced than you need for this task.

Comment: My problem with this is I need to wrap each chords function with div and a ul tags

Comment: Edited to include that.  You can break out of php inside of a function - a very useful trait of PHP.

Comment: @Tim - what about a for loop for all those `chords(n)`s?

Comment: That would be pretty trivial to implement, but the idea here is to show him how functions work; learners need to grasp one concept at a time.

Comment: Hey that worked a charm! I changed the `$fretnumbers` variable to a global like this `$GLOBALS['fretnumbers'];` and `$chord_name` like this `$GLOBALS['chord_name'];` and it worked! Thanks a lot. Am I using globals in an insecure way?

Comment: Eh, pretty much everybody does.

Comment: @Tim - Careful with you IDs, you're using the same `#chords_wrapper` multiple times

Comment: Again, an HTML error introduced by the author, not really the point of the question, but yeah, that is a problem.

Comment: @Tim - Creating redundant IDs is a recurrent general problem if you use PHP functions to create HTML. The OP will keep running into this same problem over and over again, so it's best to give them a heads up imo.

Comment: What is the problem with the #chords_wrapper being repeated?

Comment: @warmwhisky - The id attribute must be unique in a document: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple IDs with the same name of `chords_wrapper`! That's not valid. Maybe you can concatenate something to the end of the id to differentiate.

Hard to say without knowing what cords is, but you can definitely replace the multiple chords echos with a single [`for`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) or [`foreach`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/foreach) loop. And you could make the whole block into a function. I'm unclear as to the variables exactly, but something like this:

```
<?php
// $instance is a number / string you can pass in to differentiate your id
// not really sure what you're up to w $i1, $i2, and $i3
function makeCord($chord_name, $i1, $i2, $i3, $fretnumbers, $instance)
{
    $GLOBALS['i1'] = $i1;
    $GLOBALS['i2'] = $i2;
    $GLOBALS['i3'] = $i3;

    $chords = array_map('chords', range(6,1));

    ?>
    <div id="chords_wrapper<?php echo $instance; ?>" class="chords_wrapper">
        <?php 
        echo $fretnumbers;
        echo "<h1>$chord_name</h1>";            
        foreach ($chords as $chord)  
        {
            echo "<ul>$chord</ul>";
        }
        ?>
     </div>
     <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I fear that `$i1` - `$i3` are global variables (otherwise there would be no use of setting them in the question and therefore those won't need to be a function parameter). Better than for is foreach if you aim for readability, I'll change that.

Comment: Tim answered this on for me now, but thanks for your input. Do you mean its not valid to have class and ids of the same name or repeating the chords_wrapper ids?

Comment: @hakre - Thanks, you're right about the foreach combined with the array_map. It's a neat pattern.

Comment: @warmwhisky - You can have as many CSS class instances of the same name as you want. But each CSS id must be unique: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: Thanks Peter. I never knew that. Shameful, I am sure, but I have learnt something new. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a set up for a basic php function. However, based on your posted code, it's entirely unclear where the `$fretnumbers` variable is set or what you are trying to accomplish with the `&i` variables and the `chord (*)` statement.

```
<?php
    $kn = '25';
    echo '<div id="chords_set">';

        // A Major
        $i1 = '4';
        $i2 = '7';
        $i3 = '0';
        chord_dump('fretnumbershere', 'A Major');


        // A 7
        $i1 = '4';
        $i2 = '7';
        $i3 = '10';
        chord_dump('fretnumbershere', 'A 7');


        // A Minor
        $i1 = '3';
        $i2 = '7';
        $i3 = '0';
        chord_dump('fretnumbershere','A Minor');


        // A Minor 7
        $i1 = '3';
        $i2 = '7';
        $i3 = '10';
        chord_dump('fretnumbershere','A Minor 7');



        echo '<div style="width:620px; text-align:center; clear:both;">

        </div>


    </div>';

function chord_dump($fretnumbers, $chord_name) {
 $chords= '<div id="chords_wrapper" class="chords_wrapper">.'
        $fretnumbers.'
        <h1>'.$chord_name.'</h1>
        <ul>'.chords (6).'</ul>
            <ul>'.chords (5).'</ul>
            <ul>'.chords (4).'</ul>
            <ul>'.chords (3).'</ul>
            <ul>'.chords (2).'</ul>
            <ul>'.chords (1).'</ul>
        </div>';

    echo chords;
    }

?>
```

Comment: The function works great, that is not the problem. The simple problem I have is I want to print out the function calls from a variable. The code I posted at the top work. look here http://www.gtdb.org/tuning_links/chord_generator/chords_all.php I just want to tidy that code up so its easier to ad another group.

Comment: I don't know how it could "work great" when there are stated errors on your page. And the code I posted show you how to call the same function repeatedly with one line of code.

Comment: @warmwhisky: If you're looking for real good suggestions, you should add the source of the `chords` function to your question as well.

Comment: The source of the chord function is not the issue. Tim has answered this for me now and I have it working as I did before but the code is now more scalable for me.